# Finding out if a function is invertible: $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$, $g(x)=2x$ and $f$ with cases

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ such that $g(x)=2x$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x 2 &, x\in\mathbb N_{even}\\
>                                       x+9 &,x\in\mathbb N_{odd}\end{cases}$
>   Are the functions invertible?

I think I just need to find a function for each of them $f^{-1},g^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}\circ f= f\circ f^{-1}= id_{\mathbb N}$ and the same for $g$.

So is it enough to just build the functions like so:

$$g^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x 2 &, x\in\mathbb N_{even}\\
                                      1 &,x\in\mathbb N_{odd}\end{cases}$$ 
$$f^{-1}=\begin{cases} 2x &, x\in\mathbb N_{even} \\ x-9&,x\in\mathbb N_{odd}\end{cases}$$

And then show that $f^{-1}\circ f= f\circ f^{-1}= id_{\mathbb N}$ and likewise for $g$?

Comment: You should check whether or not the functions are injective and surjective. It that is the case, you can conclude that the functions are invertible. Hint: is $3 \in \text{image} \: (g)$? And the same for $f$.

Comment: @NigelOvermars so finding a function that returns every $f(x)$ back to its source isn't the right approach?

Comment: It is part of the right approach. But an inverse function needs to work both ways. You've defined a function $g^{-1}$ such that $g^{-1}\circ g$ is the identity function; so far so good. But is $g\circ g^{-1}$ the identity function?

Comment: @GregMartin yeah I thought $2g^{-1}(x)$ would be $x$ for evens, same as $g^{-1}(2x)$, only difference would be $2$ and $1$ respectively for the odds case.